# Protobuf Fields - Deprecating a parameter as google.protobuf.Any instead of reserved

Tags: field, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

Due to a circular dependency issue. We needed deprecate and `reserved` a parameter `foo`. However, we also want to continue supplanting that parameter on older versions of our App for `foo`.

Instead of making a `reserved` parameter: Is it okay to return it as a `google.protobuf.Any` with no repercussions?

Answer (score 0):

No you shouldn't. This is a breaking contract that compromised several platforms. The best way is to create new files subverting it.